# Get the value of an option button in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

If I have the following jQuery mobile html;

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" name="Smoker" id="Smoker">
  <input name="radio3" id="radio3" value="Yes" type="radio" />
  <label for="radio3">Yes</label>
  <input name="radiobuttons1" id="radio4" value="No" type="radio" />
  <label for="radio4">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

I thought I could do this in jQuery;

```
$("#Smoker").val()
```

However this yields no result.  Do I in fact need to query both the inputs to see which one has been checked or is there a nice jQuery Mobile way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try

```
$("#Smoker :radio:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 5):

First your radio buttons should have the same name attribute, otherwise selecting one doesn't deselct the other, so instead of your current markup you should have something like the following

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" name="Smoker" id="Smoker">
  <input name="smokerRdo" id="radio3" value="Yes" type="radio" />
  <label for="radio3">Yes</label>
  <input name="smokerRdo" id="radio4" value="No" type="radio" />
  <label for="radio4">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

AS for getting the value it's the same as regular jQuery, however your trying to get the value of the fieldset, not the radio group, instead try

```
 $('input[name=smokerRdo]:checked').val()
```

Comment: Your radio buttons aren't defined correctly, they should share the same name attribute. I updated my answer.